# Get closest neighbors and sort afterwards

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with following relevant columns:

```
index | name
------------
1       John
2       Steve
3       Bill
4       Dave
5       Bart
```

I want to select the first two *closest names with index smaller than 4* and I want these results to be sorted ascending by index. So I want to select:

```
index | name
------------
2       Steve
3       Bill
```

I came up with the following query:

```
SELECT index, name
FROM (
    SELECT index, name
    FROM my_table
    WHERE index < 4
    ORDER BY index DESC
    LIMIT 2
) s
ORDER BY index ASC;
```

This query works as I intended. But I am wondering if there is a better/smarter way to do this. So this question is mostly out of interest to rewrite this working query, to learn from the alternatives.

I am using PostgreSQL 10.1.

Comment: `closest names` <-- can you define what this means here?

Comment: From the query he wrote, I guess OP means the two names with the max index below 4.

Comment: It's actually `closest names with index smaller than 4`. So I want the names which have an index smaller than `4` and I only want the first two closest to `4`.

Comment: As you want to filter to two records based on a descending order, then display in an ascending order, nested queries such as your example are normally the way to go.  You could use `ROW_NUMBER()`, etc, but you'd still end up with a nested query.

Comment: Your query is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CTE instead of the nested query, which might (or might not) be easier to read:

```
WITH two_below_four AS (
    SELECT index, name
    FROM my_table
    WHERE index < 4
    ORDER BY index DESC
    LIMIT 2
)
SELECT * FROM two_below_four ORDER BY index;
```

Also, you can omit the ASC from the outer ORDER BY because ascending order is the default.

Note that for the posted data, the following queries also work:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE index IN (4-2,4-1) ORDER BY index; 

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE index >= 4-2 and index < 4 ORDER BY index; 

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE index BETWEEN 4-2 and 4-1 ORDER BY index; 

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE index >= 4-2 ORDER BY index LIMIT 2;
```

Of course these work only if there are no "gaps" in the indexes.